# Jmeter - Sending forms with file through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, file, jmeter

I have a problem with sending form with file through JavaScript using Jmeter.
It simply does not succeeded. Unfortunately I do not have any logs from that situation.

But when I am sending form without file parameter through JavaScript using Jmeter it succeeded. Once I add parameter with a file it does not.

Tried to check option in Jmeter `Use multipart/form-data for POST` with file upload section filled but it does not help.

In test I am using HTTP Request sampler with:

- POST method
- multipart/form-data for POST box is checked
- In Files Upload section the following values are provided:
  File Path
  Parameter Name
  File MIME Type
- additional parameters are provided for form

**==== EDIT ====**

Before - not working

[image: BEFORE - NOT WORKING]

After changes - working

[image: AFTER - WORKING]

Comment: Consider sharing a text-based [mcve]?

Comment: How is a form posted using jmeter?

Comment: Please show the actual code, not an explanation of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just record it

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. If your application uses [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol - import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser
3. Configure your browser to use JMeter as the [proxy](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows/)
4. Copy the file you're going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
5. Perform the upload in browser
6. JMeter will generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
7. Replay the request
8. It should be successful (assuming the previous requests were, for example if you need to log in prior to uploading the file)

More information:

- [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Comment: the problem was with http headers and with url encoding. thanks for such a tutorial. It helped a lot!